# Getting autofac to work with mvc6 beta5

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, autofac, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to get autofac working with an mvc6 application I am working on. I found [this blog article](http://alexmg.com/autofac-4-0-alpha-1-for-asp-net-5-0-beta-3/) however it seems to be a little dated. It looks like its using the beta3 bits

I am using this clr version

> 1.0.0-beta5-11911

My project has these 2 references

```
"Autofac": "4.0.0-alpha2",
"Autofac.Dnx": "4.0.0-alpha2",
```

Within the article is talks about how to modify the startup.cs

```
    // Create the Autofac container builder.
        var builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();

        // Add any Autofac modules or registrations.
        builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModule());

        // Populate the services.
        builder.Populate(services);

        // Build the container.
        var container = builder.Build();
        return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
```

The above code complains about `builder.Populate(services);` giving me an error

> The type 'IServiceDescriptor' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.IServiceDescriptor, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

From me research it looks like in beta4 DependencyInjection.IserviceDescriptor was removed.

Has anyone else managed to get autofac working with the latest beta5 bits?

Comment: A slight modification got it working
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Create the container and use the default application services as a fallback
            AutofacRegistration.Populate(builder, services);
            //   builder.RegisterType<ILogger>().As<Logger>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.Register(c => new Logger())
                 .As<ILogger>()
                 .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

Comment: We're still working on beta 5 support. We need that for configuration support, too. Check the Autofac MyGet feed for the latest; we probably won't push to NuGet until VS also works with beta 5 nicely.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm using mvc6 beta5 + latest version of Autofac from the myget feed and it's resulting in the following exception: `System.MissingMethodException
Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.TryAdd(Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceDescriptor)'.`

Comment: As described by this blog post http://alexmg.com/autofac-packages-for-visual-studio-2015-and-asp-net-5/ you will need to add the package `Autofac.Framework.DependencyInjection` instead of `Autofac.Dnx`

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who would be looking how to get AutoFac running below configuration allowed me to use it in beta6

Below is snippet of project.json

```
  "dependencies": {
"Autofac": "4.0.0-beta6-110",
"Autofac.Framework.DependencyInjection": "4.0.0-beta6-110",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta6",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta6",
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta6"
},
```

And then part of startup.cs

```
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        //create Autofac container build
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        //populate the container with services here..
        builder.RegisterType<DemoService>().As<IProjectDemo>();
        builder.Populate(services);

        //build container
        var container = builder.Build();

        //return service provider
        return container.ResolveOptional<IServiceProvider>();
    }
```

As mentioned by @peco make sure you have

```
using Autofac.Framework.DependencyInjection
```

And that got me going notime with AutoFac :) Hope this helps!

Comment: This is now Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection :)

Comment: right, for RC1 in project.json we need to use these dependencies:
"Autofac": "4.0.0-rc1-177",
"Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "4.0.0-rc1-177"