# DI autofac & mvc 6 beta7

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofac

I'm having trouble with Autofac resolve. I can't use this with mvc 6 beta7.

Using dependences:

```
  "Autofac": "4.0.0-beta7-130",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta7",
```

My Startup.cs

```
 public IContainer Container { get; set; }
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        // Create the autofac container
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        // Create the container and use the default application services as a fallback
        //AutofacRegistration.Populate(builder, services);

        // Add any Autofac modules or registrations.
        builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModule());

        Container = builder.Build();

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        //app.Run(async (context) =>
        //{
        //    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        //});
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            // Uncomment the following line to add a route for porting Web API 2 controllers.
            // routes.MapWebApiRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id?}");
        });

        app.ApplicationServices = Container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
    }
```

Take this exception

> An exception of type 'Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException' occurred in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The requested service 'System.IServiceProvider' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

How to use autofac with MVC 6 beta 7?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/docs/autofac/en/latest/integration/mvc.html)? You need to register the services first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting autofac to work with mvc6 beta5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551700/getting-autofac-to-work-with-mvc6-beta5)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the ConfigureServices method with the following to get autofac to work.

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // Add MVC services to the services container.
   services.AddMvc();

   // Create the autofac container
   var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
   // Create the container and use the default application services as a fallback
   //AutofacRegistration.Populate(builder, services);

   // Populate the services.
   builder.Populate(services);

   // Add any Autofac modules or registrations.
   builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModule());

   Container = builder.Build();

   // Resolve and return the service provider.
   return Container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
}
```