# Getting Autofac to work with MVC6/ASP.NET5

Tags: c#, autofac

I cannot get autofac to work, I have looked at this [potentially duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551700/getting-autofac-to-work-with-mvc6-beta5) question, but it doesn't help.

I am using the full .NET stack, **DNX 4.5.1**

I have included the following dependencies.

```
  "dependencies": {
    // matched latest autofac version with latest dependencyinjection version.
    "Autofac": "4.0.0-beta8-157",
    "Autofac.Framework.DependencyInjection": "4.0.0-beta8-157",    
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final" ...
```

And the following initialisation code.

```
// void?
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddMvc();

     var container = new ContainerBuilder();
     ...
     // compilation error here!
     container.Populate(services);
}
```

I am receiving this error:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert
from'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection' to
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceDescriptor>' 
MuWapp.DNX 4.5.1    C:\MuWapp\Startup.cs    54  Active
```

Comment: I think that all of the nuget package version should match (you have beta-8 and rc-1 mixed).

Comment: There is no rc-1 for autofac, so if you're correct, rc1 is not yet supported by autofac?
Which means that the rc had breaking changes, that's a bit off sides!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comment, you should use compatible versions of all packages in your project.json. I see on their page: https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/releases that they have released version for RC1, however there is no Autofac.Framework.DependencyInjection for RC1, so if you require this package, you will be unable to run it.

I think you should use built-in dependency injection during your development untill there is RTM version and all of the third-party packages will become stable.

Build-in DI has functionality for injecting classes into controllers, properties as well as attributes, so unless you use some advanced scenarios in which autofac is necessary, you should stick to asp.net 5 DI.

Comment: Thanks - obviously I need the RC1 dependency injection to use autofac with ASP.NET vNext DI. I will therefore have to wait.

Answer (score 3):

For RC1 you will need to use the Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection package.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/

We renamed our package to align with Microsoft's rename to Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection. It's been a moving target supporting the early DNX releases.